# IE developer tools: source does not showing Complete HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer

i am implementing purechat in my website, its working on all browsers except on ie, but i am surprised that content of pure chat is showing on the page, but can't find it in page source and even can't find using F12, by viewing element in ie, can it be possible to hide HTML from uses?[image]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know with IE developer tools you need to refresh the html using the refresh icon above the viewing area. Perhaps you could try that?

Alternatively it is quite possible that purechat works through an iframe which is difficult to view on IE.

As a first step I would try and find the purechat code by looking on a browser with better development tools like Google Chrome.

---

**Update**

After further research I have found that purechat appears as html **not as an iframe**. I believe the issue you are having is because IE developer tools have not updated the html. **Hit that refresh button to sort it** :)

Purechat works by injecting some JavaScript into your page, try looking for some code just before your body tag that looks similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () { var done = false; var script = document.createElement("script"); script.async = true; script.type = "text/javascript"; script.src = "https://www.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript"; document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script); script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) { var w = new PCWidget({ c: 'f509d702-fe1e-4761-9c6f-a386765ff3c7', f: true }); done = true; } }; })();
</script>
```

The actual html of the purechat widget looks like this:

```
<div class="purechat purechat-widget purechat-widget-collapsed purechat-bottom purechat-bottom-left">
  <div class="purechat-widget-inner purechat-clearfix">
    <div class="purechat-widget-header">
      <div class="purechat-menu btn-toolbar">
        <button class="btn btn-mini actions btn-collapse" style="display: none;"><i class="icon-minus"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-mini actions btn-expand"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="purechat-widget-title purechat-widget-title-collapsed">
        <img class="purechat-title-image" src="https://www.purechat.com/Content/images/icon-small.png">
        &nbsp;
        <span class="purechat-widget-title-link" title="Chat with us.">Chat with us.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="purechat-content purechat-widget-content" style="display: none;">
      <div class="purechat-enterinfo-container">
        <p>Enter your name to begin!</p>
      </div>
      <form class="purechat-init-form" action="">
        <p class="alert alert-error init-error please-entername" style="display:none;">Please enter a name.</p>
        <input type="text" class="purechat-name-input" name="purechat-name-input" placeholder="Name" maxlength="40">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" id="purechat-name-submit" value="Send Chat Request">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="purechat-poweredby-container">
      <span class="purechat-poweredby">Powered by </span><a target="_blank" href="http://www.purechat.com">PureChat.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i refresh the page, but result is same, also in google crome and mozila and even ie 9, i can view div which contain the pure chat, but in case of (BM-ie9, Document Mode ie7 standard), i can't find div or anything in   purechat content

Comment: Thanks, i was refreshing the page but its showing me div when i refresh from developer tool :)